# handsontable customizing renderer and numeric format not working

Tags: javascript, jsp, format, handsontable, renderer

I'm trying to customize the renderer and the numeric format for the same handsontable cell with no luck. Either specifying the customized renderer or the numeric format works fine, but when applying both to the same cell the numeric format is ignored.

Here is a simple sample code which demonstrates the issue. Without cellProperties.renderer = firstRowRenderer; 1.5 is correctly displayed as 1,50 €, with that line 1.5 is displayed (in bold green).

**JSP**

```
<div id="exampleGrid"></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function firstRowRenderer(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
       Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer.apply(this, arguments);
       td.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
       td.style.color = '#177B57';
       td.style.background = '#CEC';
  }
var contExample = document.getElementById("exampleGrid");
var ExampleHOT;
var language = {
            delimiters: {
                thousands: '.',
                decimal: ','
            },
            abbreviations: {
                thousand: 'k',
                million: 'm',
                billion: 'b',
                trillion: 't'
            },
            ordinal: function (number) {
                return '.';
            },
            currency: {
                symbol: '€'
            }
        };
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && this.numeral && this.numeral.language)  {
      this.numeral.language('de', language);
  }  
  function ExampleTable(){
      ExampleHOT = new Handsontable(contExample,{
        data: [ [1.5], [] ],
        rowHeaders: true,
        colHeaders: true,
        cells: function (row, col, prop) {
            var cellProperties = {};
            cellProperties.renderer = firstRowRenderer; // removing this line makes the format work
            cellProperties.type = 'numeric';
            cellProperties.format = '0.00 $';
            cellProperties.language = 'de';

            return cellProperties;
        }
    });}

    ExampleTable();
```

Has anybody found a solution for that ? 
Many thanks !

Answer (score 4):

Can you try to change this line :

```
Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer.apply(this, arguments);
```

By this line :

```
Handsontable.renderers.NumericRenderer.apply(this, arguments);
```

Good luck ;)

Comment: Even when this answer is quite old (3 years) it saved my life today, after a couple day looking for this. Thanks!